# AJAX Receiving multiple NodeJS Responses for Single Request

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express

I am building a WebApp that includes heavy AJAX calling from the frontend and NodeJS Express at the backend. My Frontend Code looks like this-

This is the global AJAX function I am using in my all projects-

```
function _ajax(params = {}, next = null, url = '', method = 'post', carry = null) {
        params = this._isObjectValid(params, 1, -1) ? params : {};

        for (let key in params) {
            if (params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                const checkObject = params[key];
                if (typeof checkObject === 'object' || Array.isArray(checkObject)) {
                    params[key] = JSON.stringify(checkObject);
                }
            }
        }

        const httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        httpRequest.open(method, url, true);
        httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        const p = Object.keys(params).map(function (value) {
            return encodeURIComponent(value) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(params[value]);
        }).join('&');

        if (next) {
            httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
                next(httpRequest, carry);
            };
        }

        httpRequest.send(p);
    }
```

This is the global Click Event Binding function

```
function _click(next, target, node, extra = null) {
        node.onclick = (event) => {
            next(event, target, extra);
        };
        return node;
    },
```

This is my AJAX Request

```
_click(
            () => {
                _ajax(
                        {mod: 'login'},
                        (request) => {
                            console.info(request.status);
                            console.info(request.response);
                        },
                        'http://localhost:1008/'
                )
            }, null, buttonSubmit);
```

My Backend Code for Handling Post AJAX Requests is:

```
app.post('*', async (req, res) => {
    console.info('POST RECEIVED');

    const params = req.body;
    console.info(params);
    await posts(req, res, params, dbo);
});

export async function posts(req, res, params, dbo) {
    if (res) {
        const mod = params.mod;
        switch (mod) {
            case 'user':
                await sendPass(res, 'User Will', null);
                break;
            default:
                await send(res, 'Invalid Module Call', null);
        }
    }
}

export function send(res, message, data, result = false) {
    res.send({result: result, message: message, data: data});
    res.end();
}

export function sendError(res, message, data) {
    send(res, message, data, false);
}

export function sendPass(res, message, data) {
    send(res, message, data, true);
}
```

Now in any other server like PHP or .NET, my web app is getting exactly one response from the server when I click the button, but for NodeJS I am getting three responses while I am processing the AJAX request only once-

[image: Sending Only One Post Request]

[image: Server Receiving Only One Post Request]

[image: Client Receiving Three Responses, First One Is Blank]

This is repeating for every AJAX Request. So If I'm processing 3 AJAX Requests, my Web App is receiving 9 responses. I tried to search on the internet on this but can't find much. Since this scenario is not repeating on any other Server except NodeJs, so it may be not a problem from JavaScript event binding or ajax processing, or a browser issue.

Any suggestion will be appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You define `node.onclick` inside the `_click` function, so I suspect one more `click` handler gets added every time this function is called. In the end, when you click once, the handler triggers multiple times.

Comment: It is not possible for the server to send a response 3 times to a single ajax request. You are sending 3 ajax requests.

Comment: @KevinB But if you see the first screenshot I have posted, It clearly showing 6 Get Requests and 1 Post Request. And as I have mentioned, this is working on other servers perfectly. I am getting one response per Post request.

Comment: @JeremyThille No. Please refer to my previous comment to Kevin B.

Comment: @HimanshuAgrawal that may be the case, but, what you are describing isn't how HTTP works.

Comment: @KevinB Any idea what is the cause of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the bug in the global AJAX function. I need to detect the status of readyState of httpRequest. I'm posting an updated version of the function:

**Before:**

```
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
   next(httpRequest, carry);
};
```

**After:**

```
/**
* readyState values
* 0: request not initialized
* 1: server connection established
* 2: request received
* 3: processing request
* 4: request finished and response is ready
*/


httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (httpRequest.readyState === 4)
        next(httpRequest, carry);
};
```

Surprisingly, it was not creating problems in other servers like WAMP or .NET for reasons I still don't know.